# Why is this (object oriented) php script not returning a value?

Tags: php

The following is a very simple script I've written in object oriented php:

```
class Comment
{
    private $commentID;

    public function set_commentID()
    {
        $this->commentID = 44;
    }
    public function get_commentID()
    {
        return $this->commentID;
    }


}

    $post = new Comment();

    echo $post->get_commentID();
```

For some reason this does not echo a value, but I'm uncertain as to why. Can anyone understand why this is not working?

Many thanks

Comment: What value do you expect it to echo?  `$commentID` was never set to anything.

Comment: Was it not set as 44?

Comment: Not unless you actually call that method.

Comment: No, you're just defining a class method called set_commentID. It doesn't automatically run.

Comment: just use $post->set_commentID() before you do $post->get_commentID()

Comment: I'd suggest you use `var_dump`/`print_r`/`var_export` when looking at return values, they show you the type and exact contents. Here you would have seen `null` for the value with most of these, but `echo` converts null to an empty string.

Comment: if you plan to use a static number in set_commentID, it would make more sense to put that in `__construct()` and then do `set_commentID($id)` instead.  Actually it makes more sense to just put it in when defining the property... muah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no value to echo.  `$commentID` was never set to anything:

```
$post = new Comment();
echo $post->get_commentID();
```

You could call your other method to set a value:

```
$post = new Comment();
$post->set_commentID(); // here
echo $post->get_commentID();
```

Other options include setting a default value in the class itself, such as in a constructor.